# Creating a Connection String with option - HDR=NO

Tags: vba, excel

note: I realize this question is similar to 512143, but this is in Excel only.

Although I could do this other ways, I wanted to learn the technique in [This Article](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/open-populate-template-excel-vba/), which uses a recordset to transfer data. My problem is this: I don't have headers on my data (well, they are on the left... not above) so I was mysteriously NOT getting my first row into my template worksheet. I narrowed the issue down to the connection string NOT specifying the absence of headers.

```
connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & ActiveWorkbook.FullName & ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"
connDB.Open connStr
```

when I change it to:

```
connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & ActiveWorkbook.FullName & ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;"
```

I get the "Could not find installable ISAM" error, which I don't understand.
I searched for answers and found questions: 37251084, 512143
So I tried:

```
connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & ActiveWorkbook.FullName & ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;'"
```

which gave the error: "Format of initializing string does not conform to OLE DB specifications"

so now I will either give up (which is no good since I have to integrate this data system into Access eventually and should understand this type of thing.)
or do some makeshift fix where there are blank headers above the data. Which is lame.
After a few hours of searching for something I can understand relating to connection strings I am kinda spent, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & ActiveWorkbook.FullName & ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1;';"

Comment: `"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & ActiveWorkbook.FullName & ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1'"`

Comment: omg, the one you put up still returned an error, but then I just started deleting off the end one at a time and poof! this worked! ty it is fixed!

Comment: The IMEX 1 allows for mixed data types btw.

Answer (score 0):

This provider string worked on: Microsoft Excel 2016 MSO (16.0.9126.2109) 32-bit

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & ActiveWorkbook.FullName &
";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1'"
```

for the full technique, I give credit to Felix Hooker at Datanumen. [Here](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/open-populate-template-excel-vba/) he gives the full code, which I found useful as a macro for creating saved data files from template in a scientific type data processing spreadsheet, without flashing windows open and closed when the user clicks a button!